# What is the quickest way to get a local EOS Block Explorer up and running?

Tags: development, explorer

I would love to have an EOS Block Explorer on my local machine for during development.

Would be a great development tool :-). 
Who can provide me the steps / tools to get it up and running?

Comment: do you mean a database with the blocks or a block explorer app including a web front-end?

Comment: A block explorer app including a web front-end :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

https://github.com/harrythedev/eos-block-explorer

This repo uses `eosjs` to retrieve blocks.

If you feel like more detailed data, you may also enable `mongo_db_plugin` and use a mongo GUI client to query (like Robo 3t).